# how to publish photo on application profile page using REST api of facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ip

i am uploading photo to application(or like) profile page. But it will show error message

"error_code":240,"error_msg":"Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user."

i am using REST API for facebook.

And this code 
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   img, @"picture",
                                   kAppId,@"uid",
                                   nil];

```
[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                       andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                     andDelegate:self];
```

where kAppId is applicatino ID.
 if i remove @"Uid" parameter then photo uploaded to my(user) photo album.

this thing is possible in web that user can upload a photo to like page as news feed.
how we can do it through REST APi

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try urlencoding your params using

```
[params dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

Comment: i thing u not get my problem.
what parameter i use so that photo should upload in album of application & also feed publish on application page.
Thanks